# WIX/DTF - Dialog with a list, edit field and add/remove buttons on it

Tags: installation, wix, wix3, dtf

Anybody knows a good source to get an idea how to create this kind of a dialog?
I'm well aware that I'll need to write some CA's for that but relatively new to WiX (used to work with InstallShield).

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/WiXAndDTFUsingACustomActionToListAvailableWebSitesOnIIS.aspx) can get you started. Does not contain info about edit fields and buttons, but have a listbox. As an example, it populates IIS websites into the listbox. Very good source of info.

Comment: thanks! i actually read that article and another one on Christopher Painter's blog.